# Add line break after n characters, but if it's in the middle of a word cut the whole word and add in next line

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I am trying to add line break in text area after every 69 characters. I don't want to cut words in middle. if split occurs in middle of the word, take the entire word and put in next line. sample sentence is as follows:

```
      var sample_txt = "I THOUGHT IT WAS A SIMPLE CONCEPT \nAND DIDN'T FEEL CODE WAS REQUIRED. THE ANSWERS SO FAR SEEM TO HAVE UNDERSTOOD MY EXPLANATION AND SO I AM TRYING THEIR SOLUTIONS NOW. IF I DON'T HAVE ANY JOY I'LL POST SOME CODE. MY IMPLEMENTATION IS ACTUALLY MUCH MORE COMPLEX \nI THOUGHT IT WAS A SIMPLE CONCEPT AND DIDN'T FEEL CODE WAS REQUIRED. THE ANSWERS SO FAR SEEM TO HAVE UNDERSTOOD MY EXPLANATION AND SO I AM TRYING THEIR SOLUTIONS NOW. IF I DON'T HAVE ANY JOY I'LL POST SOME CODE. MY IMPLEMENTATION IS ACTUALLY MUCH MORE COMPLEX";

      $(document).on('blur', 'TEXTAREA', function () {
            var arr_lines = sample_txt.split('\n'),
                char_limit = 69,
                txt_val = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < arr_lines.length; i++){
                if(arr_lines[i].length > char_limit){
                    var patern = new RegExp('(.{' + (char_limit-1) + '})', 'gi'),
                        arr_txt = arr_lines[i].replace(patern, "$1\n");
                    $.each(arr_txt.split('\n'), function(i,vl){
                        txt_val.push(vl.trim());
                    });
                }else{
                    txt_val.push(arr_lines[i].trim());
                }
            }
            this.value = txt_val.join('\n');
        });
```

The string also contains line break entered by the user. I am a spliting them based on '\n' and then count characters and split them again if character exceed limit. the output should be as follows:

```
I THOUGHT IT WAS A SIMPLE CONCEPT  
AND DIDN'T FEEL CODE WAS REQUIRED. THE ANSWERS SO FAR SEEM TO HAVE 
UNDERSTOOD MY EXPLANATION AND SO I AM TRYING THEIR SOLUTIONS NOW. IF
I DON'T HAVE ANY JOY I'LL POST SOME CODE. MY IMPLEMENTATION IS 
ACTUALLY MUCH MORE COMPLEX 
I THOUGHT IT WAS A SIMPLE CONCEPT AND DIDN'T FEEL CODE WAS REQUIRED.
THE ANSWERS SO FAR SEEM TO HAVE UNDERSTOOD MY EXPLANATION AND SO I 
AM TRYING THEIR SOLUTIONS NOW. IF I DON'T HAVE ANY JOY I'LL POST 
SOME CODE. MY IMPLEMENTATION IS ACTUALLY MUCH MORE COMPLEX
```

I looked at some examples at stackoverflow.com but most of the example I found, they just limit the character in one line. They don't put the word in next line.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl has the substitution operator, and for this problem, it would be

to get rid of the newlines in the string first

```
s/\n//g
```

Then add new line after 69 or less characters followed by a space or at the end of the string

```
s/(.{1,69})(?:$| )/$1\n/g
```

It matches up to 69 characters and spaces followed by the end of the string or a space. It then places a newline in the place after the captured, `$1`, text.

The g modifier tells it to do this replacement globally (over the whole string). However, this will place a newline at the very end of the string and I don't know if that is what you need.

The result was below.

I THOUGHT IT WAS A SIMPLE CONCEPT AND DIDN'T FEEL CODE WAS REQUIRED.
THE ANSWERS SO FAR SEEM TO HAVE UNDERSTOOD MY EXPLANATION AND SO I AM
TRYING THEIR SOLUTIONS NOW. IF I DON'T HAVE ANY JOY I'LL POST SOME
CODE. MY IMPLEMENTATION IS ACTUALLY MUCH MORE COMPLEX I THOUGHT IT
WAS A SIMPLE CONCEPT AND DIDN'T FEEL CODE WAS REQUIRED. THE ANSWERS
SO FAR SEEM TO HAVE UNDERSTOOD MY EXPLANATION AND SO I AM TRYING
THEIR SOLUTIONS NOW. IF I DON'T HAVE ANY JOY I'LL POST SOME CODE. MY
IMPLEMENTATION IS ACTUALLY MUCH MORE COMPLEX

However, if you want to keep the original line breaks, like this:

I THOUGHT IT WAS A SIMPLE CONCEPT

AND DIDN'T FEEL CODE WAS REQUIRED. THE ANSWERS SO FAR SEEM TO HAVE
UNDERSTOOD MY EXPLANATION AND SO I AM TRYING THEIR SOLUTIONS NOW. IF
I DON'T HAVE ANY JOY I'LL POST SOME CODE. MY IMPLEMENTATION IS
ACTUALLY MUCH MORE COMPLEX

I THOUGHT IT WAS A SIMPLE CONCEPT AND DIDN'T FEEL CODE WAS REQUIRED.
THE ANSWERS SO FAR SEEM TO HAVE UNDERSTOOD MY EXPLANATION AND SO I AM
TRYING THEIR SOLUTIONS NOW. IF I DON'T HAVE ANY JOY I'LL POST SOME
CODE. MY IMPLEMENTATION IS ACTUALLY MUCH MORE COMPLEX

the code for this would be  more difficult.

```
s/(.{1,69})(?:(?=\n)|$| )/$1\n/g
```

**Update:** After seeing your edited post with the required output, I see what you want. The regular expression that would give those results is

```
s/(.{1,69})(?:\n|$| )/$1\n/g
```

(Ignore the solutions I gave above).

**Update2:** for jquery, which I don't really know, the syntax needs to be (after doing some searching on the [web](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)), I think I found the correct solution.

```
this.value = sample_txt.replace(/(.{1,69})(?:\n|$| )/g, "$1\n");
```

Comment: I want to keep the original line breaks and then I want to limit the characters to 69. After that it should add another line break.

Comment: @sarojanand I've updated my post. The regular expression there does what you want. (Note that dot matches every character except a newline).

Comment: Chris, can you please add the full line of syntax? I removed everything and added it like "this.value = txt_val.replace('s/(.{1,69})(?:\n|$| )/$1\n/g');" but I dont see it working.

Comment: @sarojanand I made a slight change to Update2. replaced `txt_val` with `sample_txt`

Comment: this is great only an issue. I put 69 but I see the text are going up-to 70 characters. If I change the number to 68 char max, then it goes up-to 69 characters. Is there any reason its going one extra char than the specified max limit?

Comment: @sarojanand When I do a document.write() here (I can't get the Jquery to run, I don't know enough about it), the longest string I got was 69. The only thing I can think why you are counting 70 characters is if you count the newline, `\n`, as well. Sorry, but I can't say why this is happening for you. I am just know learning JavaScript and XHTML. Could you recommend a good book to learn JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a textarea, you can use the `cols` attribute to specify the number of characters you want on each line. This also handles the case when the user enters a line break.

This value is 20 by default in HTML5 (reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-cols)

**Sample code:**

```
<textarea cols="69"> <!--Maximum of 69 characters when there are spaces in the text-->
</textarea>
```

If you want to do it programatically, please refer the following article on *Word Wrap Problem* http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-18-word-wrap/

Comment: I need a jQuery solution. cols are already defined to 69 but it doesn't work as the width is 100%.